# How can I associate labels with form fields outside them in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript

Let's say I'm creating labels and form fields in a *ngFor loop like this:

#### app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  items = ['aaa', 'bbbbbb', 'ccccccccc']
}
```

#### app.component.html

```
<div class='form'>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <label>{{item|uppercase}}:</label>
    <input [value]="item"/>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

(See it on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptwq6t)

Is there a way to cleanly associate these "dynamic" labels and inputs with one another? If I do:

```
<label for="field" >{{item|uppercase}}:</label>
<input id="field" [value]="item"/>
```

Angular just repeats the `for` and `id` attributes verbatim and all labels point to the first input field.

Is there some way to use Angular's component identity, or am I stuck with something like generating a UUID myself, or otherwise guaranteeing uniqueness of the ID myself?

I can't nest the input inside the label because I have to reuse some already implemented CSS that doesn't expect that structure, but would still like the better usability that comes from having a proper label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the `items` are unique, you could surely do this:

```
<label [for]="item" >{{item|uppercase}}:</label>
<input [id]="item" [value]="item"/>
```

That way, each `id` and `for` would be unique and label would work as required.

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yecc9f).

If you anyway need to generate the unique IDs, take a look at [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid)

Comment: I mean in my dummy example they are but generally I can't guarantee this and components should be self-contained.

Comment: `shortid` looks neat though

Comment: Yeah, Because the items were being used as labels themselves, I assumed that they would be unique. Duplicate label in a form does not make sense. About `shortid`, definitely, I have seen people in react community using it quite extensively

Comment: I’ll probably go nuts and use it to make our forms submittable with Enter too like god intended

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
 <div class='form'>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
        <label for="{{item}} + 'field'" >{{item|uppercase}}:</label>
        <input id="{{item}} + 'field'" [value]="item"/>
      </ng-container>
 </div>
```

or use the ngfor index if your items are not unique:

```
<div class='form'>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <label for="{{i}} + 'field'" >{{item|uppercase}}:</label>
    <input id="{{i}} + 'field'" [value]="item"/>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fvgvmm)

Comment: did you check my answer? what is the problem?

Comment: If I use the component doing this twice on a page the IDs ‘0field’, ‘1field’ will repeat