# @ViewChild take HTMLElement from another component

Tags: angular

I have this presentation component

`add-publication.ts`

is basically an empty class

`add-publication.html`

```
<div class="file-upload" fxLayout="row">
  <div class="file-upload__portrait">
    <app-take-photo></app-take-photo>
  </div>
  <div class="file-upload__gallery" fxLayout="column">
    <app-take-photo></app-take-photo>
    <app-take-photo></app-take-photo>
    <app-take-photo></app-take-photo>
    <app-take-photo></app-take-photo>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this component

`take-photo.ts`

```
export class TakePhotoComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('img', { read: ElementRef })
  img: ElementRef<HTMLImageElement>;

  constructor(private service: TakePhotoService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  async onChange(files: FileList) {
    try {
      const result = await this.service.compressAndRemoveExifFromPhoto(files && files[0]);
      this.img.nativeElement.src = result;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

```
<img #img class="upload__preview" alt="Upload your photo">

<input id="upload" class="upload__input" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment"
  (change)="onChange($event.target.files)">
<label class="upload__action" for="upload">
  &nbsp;
</label>
```

The issue is in this component. When I click, for example, on the third component from inside `.file-upload__gallery` then `this.img` is always the first one (I mean the one inside `.file-upload__portrait`). I don't know why.

I was expecting to get `<img>` from inside the clicked component and not from another.

Is it because every `<img>` has `#img` as an identifier?

Comment: `@ViewChild` will only know about the `#img` you specify inside. There's probably some other problem with your code. You should include the code in its entirety, that will make it easier to spot the error.

Comment: Thanks for answer. As soon as I get back to home I will update it

Answer (score 0):

So, I figure out the problem.

Every component has one `input id="upload"`  and `label for="upload"`. Whenever I clicked the `label` it always points to the first `input` because these are not unique

In my case removing the `label` solves the issue.

I found a similar problem [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53406734/9513968)